# pandas dropna is not removing nan when using np.where

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have this function

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon

def test(e, n):

    polygon = Polygon([(340,6638),(340,6614),(375,6620),(374,6649)])
    point_instance = Point((e, n))

    a = polygon.contains(point_instance)
    val = np.where(a, 0, np.nan)

    return pd.Series([val])
```

I want to apply above function in my dataframe and then remove the nan

```
def testData(filename):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    df['check'] = df\
        .apply(lambda x: test(x['E'], x['N']), axis=1)

    # I tried both of these and doesnt delete nan values
    df.dropna(axis=0, how = 'any', inplace = True)
    df1 = df.dropna(axis=0, how='any', subset=['check'])
```

However, if i save data in a file and use dropna, then it works.

Sample dataframe

```
Id,E,N
1,5,8
2,6,9
3,7,10
```

This is the output I am getting

```
Id  E  N check    
1     5      8                 nan
2     6      9                 nan
3     7     10                 nan
```

Comment: have you tried with `axis=1` ?

Comment: I want to drop rows not columns for any rows which contains nan

Comment: if you want to drop rows that contains nan `df = df.dropna()` should do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems using `np.nan` inside `np.where` creates conflict datatypes. 
And for that reason, pandas dropna didnt work.

I fixed using pandas map inside my function

```
a = pd.Series(polygon.contains(point_instance))

val = a.map({True: 0, False: np.nan})
return val
```